# Realm crash when try to deleting children Objects of type Object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I Have one class UserObject(Object) that has one property of SessionObject(Object), and the SessionObject has properties of other Realm Objects(TestObject, NewObject).
When I delete the children Objects and after that the parent Object successfully, the app crashes with Bad Access: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

```
class UserObject: Object{
   dynamic var uuid = ""
   dynamic var username = ""
   dynamic var session: SessionObject?

class SessionObject: Object{
    dynamic var tokenType = ""
    dynamic var refreshToken = ""
    dynamic var test: TestObject?
    dynamic var new: NewObject?
}

class TestObject: Object{
    dynamic var test = ""
}

class NewObject: Object{
   dynamic var test = ""
}


func deleteUser(){
    guard let realm = self.realmInstance else{
        return
    }
    guard let user = Array(realm.objects(UserObject.self)).first else{
        return
    }
    do{
        try realm.write {
            if let session = user.session{
                if let test = session.test{
                    realm.delete(test)
                }
                if let new = session.new{
                    realm.delete(new)
                }
                realm.delete(session)
            }
            realm.delete(user)
        }
    }catch{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running in to [ARC naming conventions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-method-families), which apply to `dynamic` properties on Swift classes. Currently Realm does not generate accessor methods which conform to what ARC expects for specially-named methods, which results in objects being double-deleted when you have a property name starting with `new`, `copy` or `mutableCopy`.

Comment: You was right. Change the properties name solved the problem.